# Character appearance in Sprite Kit (Swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, swift3

I'm trying to build my character but i have problem maybe who
can help me.

the problem :

her arm and her legs gone and i can not bring them back in their place

my character now :

[image]

the character :

[image]

```
 func loadAppearance() {


    body = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: 100))
    body.position = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: 10)
    addChild(body)

    let skinColor = UIColor(red: 242.0/255.0, green: 209.0/255.0, blue: 179.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let face = SKSpriteNode(color: skinColor, size: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: 30))
    face.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:15)
    body.addChild(face)

    let eyeColor = UIColor.white
    let leftEye = SKSpriteNode(color: eyeColor, size: CGSize(width: 15, height: 15))
    let rightEye = leftEye.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
    let pupil = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 7.5, height: 7.5))

    pupil.position = CGPoint(x:5, y:0)
    leftEye.addChild(pupil)
    rightEye.addChild(pupil.copy() as! SKSpriteNode)

    leftEye.position = CGPoint(x:-10, y:0)
    face.addChild(leftEye)

    rightEye.position = CGPoint(x:35, y:0)
    face.addChild(rightEye)

    let eyebrow = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width:27.5, height: 2.5))
    eyebrow.position = CGPoint(x:-1, y:leftEye.size.height/2)
    leftEye.addChild(eyebrow)
    rightEye.addChild(eyebrow.copy() as! SKSpriteNode)

    let armColor = UIColor(red: 46/255, green: 46/255, blue: 46/255, alpha: 1.0)
    arm = SKSpriteNode(color: armColor, size: CGSize(width: 24, height: 42))
    arm.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.9)
    arm.position = CGPoint(x:-20, y: -14)
    body.addChild(arm)

    let hand = SKSpriteNode(color: skinColor, size: CGSize(width: arm.size.width, height: 10))
    hand.position = CGPoint(x:0 - arm.size.height*0.9 , y: hand.size.height/2)

    arm.addChild(hand)

    leftFoot = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 27, height: 12))
    leftFoot.position = CGPoint(x: -18 - size.height/2  , y: leftFoot.size.height/2 )
    addChild(leftFoot)

    rightFoot = leftFoot.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
    rightFoot.position.x = 26
    addChild(rightFoot)
}
```

Thanks you for help

Omer.

Comment: Have you looked at SKConstraints? You might not need them, but they're useful to know about: https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skconstraint

Comment: It's not happend , I need to fix the body of character

Comment: Why are you anchor points so out of whack?

Comment: So i shouldn't need to use with anchor points? You can help me to fix my problem @Knight0fDragon

Comment: anchor points are important when it comes to rotation of the Sprite, if that is why you are doing it then leave it

Comment: but my guess is you are not positioning your hand relative to your arm, shouldnt the x be 0 and the y be the arm length - hand height - 2

Comment: now apply the same type of thinking to the leg lol

Comment: @Knight0fDragon you can help me ?

Comment: you can help yourself,  already explained the hand, do the same thought to the leg